# Keyboard Layout occasionally changes

Tags: unity, 14.04, keyboard-layout

I'm using an English(UK) keyboard, I set it up so when installing Ubuntu. English(US) appears as an alternative layout in the Text Entry settings window. Every few days the layout configuration will switch to the English(US) layout.

I can revert back to the UK configuration either by removing the US layout (and then adding it back a few days later when the layout or changes again) or by toggling back and forth via the unity icon (appears as En1 styled like a chemical element).

I'd like the keyboard layout to remain as English(UK) on a permanent basis and would appreciate if anyone could explain the cause and solution to this problem.

Comment: It's possibly related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is the same bug that I suffered. I tried lots of things. If you switch from En1 to En2 & back again each time you boot up that's a workaround (using the icon in the system tray). The only permanent solution I found was to remove Ibus.

Beware! Removing Ibus removes most of the Unity System Settings too.

There's a thread here:

[Wrong Keyboard Map](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109635/wrong-keyboard-map/453089#453089)